# Current Year Post type Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've a this query post

```
<?php 
    $args = (array(
    'post_type' => 'issue_number', 
    'posts_per_page' => 13, 
    'paged' => $paged  
                    ));

    // query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>


    <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();?>

      bla bla

    <?php endwhile;  ?>
```

I want to display only current year post type (issue_number)...how to do?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
$current_year = the_date( 'Y' );

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'issue_number',
    'posts_per_page' => 13, 
    'paged' => $paged,  
    'year' => $current_year
);
```